# twitter link in app no longer works

Tags: java, android, twitter-bootstrap, rest, twitter

The following link in my android app no longer works:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=android

I am now getting the following error:

{"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}

how can I re-write this to make it work ?

I looked through some of that twitter documentation but just got lost.

Comment: Try this? https://twitter.com/search?q=android

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the [official API resource](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search), the endpoint (and the version) has been deprecated.

Rewrite your calling code (assuming it's `Java` with `HttpClient`) to point to:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=android
```

**Please note that now API v1.1 requires that the request must be authenticated, check [Authentication & Authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) documentation for more details on how to do it.**

Comment: Right, it's not working because the updated API now requires authentication/credentials to be passed in on each request. Do you have that setup already?